# Unwrap an variable number of wrapper types in a single operation

Tags: c#, types, type-inference

I have a generic wrapper type:

```
public class Wrap<T> {
    public T Contents { get; set; }
}
```

I can wrap any object in a wrap or unwrap a wrapped object:

```
public static class WrapHelpers {
    public static Wrap<T> Wrap<T>(this T contents) {
        return new Wrap<T> { Contents = contents };
    }
    public static T Unwrap<T>(this Wrap<T> wrapped) {
        return wrapped.Contents;
    }
    //NOP
    public static T Unwrap<T>(this T contents) {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Here is how I can wrap and unwrap some string:

```
string s = "ssss";
var wrappedString = s.Wrap().Wrap().Wrap();
string unwrappedString = wrappedString.Unwrap().Unwrap().Unwrap().Unwrap().Unwrap().Unwrap();
```

See how I need to unwrap multiple times to get to get to the string inside.

**What I want is to write a strongly-typed generic operation that can do the unwrapping in a single step (or constant number of steps).**
Some tools that might be useful are generic methods, lambdas, method overloads. I even thought about building type-based Y-combinatory from fixed-point combinators to use for unlimited recursion. Even recursion needs steps/cycles/iterations though.

I'm not sure this is solvable, but C#'s type inference can solve NP-hard problems (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five/) so there is still a tiny chance I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Doubt you can do that without adding overload for each wrapping level (`Unwrap<T>(this Wrap<Wrap<T>> wrapped)` etc). Is there any real world usage for such scenario?

Comment: @Evk "overload for each wrapping level" There is probably a way to only use logarithmical number of steps. But That's not too interesting for me. Similar techniques are needed for example when you want to reverse a tuple-based multi-typed linked list.

Comment: Well I think what you want is just not possible with C# type system.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, but you lose type safety and it certainly isn't in a constant number of steps :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Test
{
    public class Wrap<T>
    {
        public T Contents { get; set; }

        public object DeepUnwrap()
        {
            var wrapped = this;
            var hello = wrapped.Unwrap();

            if (hello != null)
            {
                var type = hello.GetType();

                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Wrap<>))
                    return ((dynamic)hello).DeepUnwrap();
            }

            return hello;
        }

    }

    public static class WrapHelpers
    {
        public static Wrap<T> Wrap<T>(this T contents)
        {
            return new Wrap<T> { Contents = contents };
        }
        public static T Unwrap<T>(this Wrap<T> wrapped)
        {
            return wrapped.Contents;
        }

        public static object FullUnwrap<T>(this Wrap<T> wrapped)
        {
            var hello = wrapped.DeepUnwrap();

            return hello;
        }

        //NOP
        public static T Unwrap<T>(this T contents)
        {
            return contents;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "ssss";
            var wrappedString = s.Wrap().Wrap().Wrap();
            Console.WriteLine(wrappedString.FullUnwrap());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "isn't in a constant number of steps" - For me, your solution has constant number of call-steps as you do the unwrapping in 1 step when you call ".FullUnwrap()". Unfortunately, the strict typing is violated. For example, my `wrappedString.Unwrap().....Unwrap() == "ssss"` would compile/work the same as `s == "ssss"`, but your `wrappedString.FullUnwrap() == "ssss"` won't compile or work the same.