# Replace an innermost type in a deeply-nested generic type

Tags: c#, types, type-inference

I have a generic wrapper type:

```
public class Wrap<T> {
    public T Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have a deeply wrapped string (or any other type of object):

```
Wrap<Wrap<.....Wrap<string>...>> wrappedString = ...;
```

What I want is to replace the innermost type ('string') with some other type (e.g. `List<string>`)

```
Wrap<Wrap<.....Wrap<List<string>>...>> wrappedStringList = some operation on wrappedString;
```

How can I do this?

**What I want is to write a strongly-typed generic operation (no dynamic, no reflection) that can replace the inner type.** You can modify the `Wrap<T>` class if you need (for example, you might want to leave some hooks/breadcrumbs to get to the innermost object), but it's nesting nature should be preserved..

Some tools that might be useful are generic methods, lambdas, method overloads. I though about building some reversing method/lambda/type during the wrapping process, but have not succeed yet.

I'm not sure this is solvable, but C#'s type inference can solve NP-hard problems (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five/) so there is still a tiny chance I'm overlooking something.

**Update:**
Let me make it more clear:

The operation is easy if you know the exact number of wrapping types:

The following functions can replace type wrapped in 1 or 2 layers of wrapper types:

```
public static Wrap<List<T>> Rewrap<T>(this Wrap<T> wrapped) {
    return new Wrap<List<T>> { Contents = new List<T> { wrapped.Contents } };
}

public static Wrap<Wrap<List<T>>> Rewrap<T>(this Wrap<Wrap<T>> wrapped) {
    return new Wrap<Wrap<List<T>>> { Contents = new Wrap<List<T>> { Contents = new List<T> { wrapped.Contents.Contents } } };
}
```

What I need is a generic way to do this (independent on the number of wraps).

This is an abstract question for C# language experts. If you do not like abstract questions, please do not vote it down.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well you cant change the type of an object. but you can copy it to a new object of a new type (if the conversion is internally supported) or you can just be sane and use `var` and let the compiler decide for you.

Comment: You can expose a generic method to type cast the string to integer. And call that method to get your desired type value.

Comment: I've updated the question and added examples (replacing T with List<T> inside the wraps). It's an abstract C# type system question. I do not care about object values, I care about the types.  I need a way to do this generically for any wrap depth.

Comment: @KarthikAMR Believe me, I know how to convert `string` to `int`. But the question is about getting from type `Wrap<....Wrap<TSomething>...>` to type `Wrap<....Wrap<TSomethingElse>...>`.

Comment: Type inference can't do this. Runtime manipulation can do it, of course (you need some code that tests if `T` is a `Wrap<U>` of some `U`) but you could never declare a method with a compatible return type, so ugly casts and dynamic type creation are unavoidable. I'm not sure this problem is worth solving; if this were in my code base, I'd look at ways to get rid of `Wrap` entirely, or at least the nesting, or (if absolutely necessary) overloads to the level of nesting I use. Excessive nesting of generics is a smell.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435405/unwrap-an-variable-number-of-wrapper-types-in-a-single-operation), but uncomfortably close. An answer to one is almost certainly also an answer to the other (or trivially leads to one). This needn't have been two questions.

Comment: @Ark-kun I just gave you a design to achieve what you wanted to achieve.  I didn't mean your qualifications. :)